# Select from dataset where data in dataset matches user input

Tags: c#

I am trying to query or match user input against a `dataset` using a `DataTable`:

I am populating the dataset from a stored procedure which selects only a single column from a single table: Example: UserID Column. **I am not selecting the entire content of the table.*

```
public static DataSet LoadProfile()
{
    SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("usp_LoadProfile", ConnectDatabase);
    cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlDataAdapter daSQL = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    daSQL.Fill(ds);

    try
    {
        ConnectDatabase.Open();
        cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        StatusMsg = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        ConnectDatabase.Close();
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Clear();
        cmdSQL.Dispose();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

I have the following method called in the form load event: I need to populate the dataset on from load.

```
public static DataTable LoadData()
{
    DataSet dsView = new DataSet();
    dsView = LoadProfile();
    DataTable tblExample = dsView.Tables["Example"];

    return tblExample;
}
```

Finally what I would like to do is match the user entry from the `DataTable`.

I have this in button event:

```
DataRow[] results;
results = LoadData().Select(txtExample.Text);
```

Beyond this point, I could use a for loop but there is only one record for each person.

I am trying to match the user entry with the dataset via the datatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line should be

```
DataRow[] results;
results = LoadData().Select("UserID = '" + txtExample.Text +"'");
```

Supposing that UserID is a field of text type. If instead is of numeric type then remove the quotes

```
results = LoadData().Select("UserID = " + txtExample.Text);
```

However I should point that the code in `LoadProfile` following the `daSQL.Fill(ds);` call is not needed and you can remove it (just return the DataSet though)

Comment: I get this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You need to debug the code in LoadProfile and check if it returns effectively a filled DataSet where there is a table named "Example" (Hint, use the index 0 for the first table in the dataset)

Comment: Got it! I simply used Zero for table index and a for loop at the end. Thanks for the helpful hint.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following simple query on dataset:

```
DataRow[] dRow = dataSetName.Tables[0].Select("fieldToMatch = '" + userInput.ToString() + "' ");
```